# Low quality image android development

Tags: java, android, bitmap, png

I made a photoshop image 480x2500 which I want to put in one of my activities.
But, after installing the .apk, the image has low quality. I really tried everything I found on google, without results. I'm not an experienced programmer so please take you time and explain everything that can help me.
Here are my codes:

XML:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1166dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/secondbutton3" />
```

Java Code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Secondbutton extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondbutton);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap gradient = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.secondbutton, options);

        findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(gradient));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_secondbutton, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

I tried to erase a tiny part of my image(to have a transparent background) but without results.
Thank you.

Comment: that line is wrong `android:layout_height="1166dp"`

Comment: i solved by https://makeappicon.com because android studio make image lower than expected in quality dont know why

Answer (score 1):

How do you save the image from photoshop?
Transparent png!
With export for web

Comment: I save it .png using Save for Web and Devices tab.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image is saved as a .png

Also, you probably want to run it through the Android Asset Studio, which will automatically scale the image for different screen densities.

[Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)

Comment: I used Asset Studio but the image that appears on screen is even on a worse scale.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    myOptions.inDither = true;
    myOptions.inScaled = false;
    myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    myOptions.inDither = false;
    myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap preparedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(yourAppName.getSharedApplication().getResources(),
            R.drawable.yourImage, myOptions);
    Drawable background = new BitmapDrawable(preparedBitmap);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId))
        .setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```