# Camera intent causes very low quality of picture in preview

Tags: android-camera-intent

I have an Android app which opens the camera to take a pic:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

If it is called the camera is opened and I can take picture. But the preview where to click OK or Cancel is already very bad quality.

This is strange as this is not implemented by my app. Are there any parameters to configure for the camera intent to increase the quality.

Comment: Check this link out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057320/low-quality-image-android-development

Comment: I am not storing the image. It is the preview after taking the shot which is done by android I think. This preview is already very bad quality.

Comment: I think you are getting the thumbnail image then

Comment: Yes this would explain it! But how to change this?

Comment: Everything explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821767/receiving-low-quality-image-from-camera-intent

Answer (score 0):

This example im uploading to firebase:

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        progressDialog.setMessage(UPLOADING);
        progressDialog.show();
        StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child(STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME).child(recipeTitle.getText().toString());
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateNewRecipeActivity.this, UPLOAD_COMPLETE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here im getting the full image

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

Comment: Thx. I am not talking about getting the image. It is a step before. Android lets the user take pic and shows it and gives the option to say oK or Redo. And this image is low quality. But I think the reason is that I dont give a place to store.

Comment: Ahh ok, yeah found out myself you get better image if you save it and get it afterwards, misunderstood you. Hope it fixes it then.